# IIS settings mysteriously changing "on ther own"

Tags: iis-6

We've been noticing that on one of our development servers that the Authentication settings has been mysteriously been changing from Anonymous to Windows Authentication and the "Execute Permissions" has been changing from Scripts Only to None without anyone admitting it and having only a small number of people who have the access to do it.

Short of intentional sabotage, which I doubt, has anyone ever seen anything like this?

Could it be the automated application of a group policy?

Answer (score 3):

IIS Doesn't change settings.  People do.

Comment: When I run into situations like this with IIS, it is typically people who are changing a setting at the server/site level, and propagating it down to other sites/vdirs without realizing it.

Comment: That happens all too often over here as well.  Either that or someone will make a change and someone else will revert it because they were not aware of the change that was made.

My suggestion has been to keep a list of every configuration change that is made to IIS,DNS,SQL,etc servers in a specific place (a wiki or something) so everyone knows what the settings are supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I've had this happen (in general, not just with IIS) someone's changing it and not fessing up.

These settings can also change via direct editing of the IIS metabase.  Do you have that enabled in IIS?

Answer (score 0):

Is it an Exchange server?

Exchange has an internal process that configures its web components (OWA, etc.) as it sees fit to, and routinely overwrites whatever change you make directly to IIS.

Comment: No, it's not, but nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

having the same problem here!

I think it's IIS on 2000 or IIS 5 thing.  It's driving me nutz.  We have 7 load balanced servers that should contain all the same settings.  sometimes it's just one server sometimes it's all of them.  custom headers & cache-control is one issue and I have just notice anaonymous & windows authentication getting set oddly too.

I need a batch program that will clober the settings the way they need set and have it run daily.   is this posssible???

Comment: You'd probably get better answers by asking that as a question (assuming that you don't find another question that matches yours).

Comment: We proved to ourselves that when the developers use Visual Studio 6 (from the '70s, I think) to modify ASP code on the development web server, that the settings on the Virtual folder get changed as a result.